# Raspberry Pi 2 as Car-PC: Shutdown when ignition off & boot when ignition on

Tags: power

I want to build a Car-PC, based on a Raspberry Pi with Display to play MP3´s. If I turn on the ignition in the car, the raspi should boot. When turning ignition off, the raspi has to shutdown. How can I do that? I am using ubuntu mate on raspi.

I think there must be a kind of battery between power off and shutdown: 
Key turn (ignition off) -> Raspi gets power from Battery -> raspi gets signal to shutdown -> raspi can shutdown.

Or is there any other way?

What, if just turning off the raspi by cutting it from power? Can it reboot correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend not turning off the RPi by simply pulling the plug.  The only time I've ever had to deal with a corrupted card was because of power issues.

You're correct though, you will need some kind of circuit between your power source and the RPi.  Otherwise, the RPi just dies, and it won't have time to power down. I would suggest a UPS (uninterruptable power supply) that is capable of then signaling the RPi.  Since you're more or less turning the RPi off as soon as the power is cut, you can get by with a pretty small battery.

I would suggest something like: http://www.piups.net.  It already has the signal interface built in, you just need to handle the logic.